# Thew object miss your reference with model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code html que uses ** ** ng-repeat and I bind your properties with ** ng-model **. But when I step your reference through a method and I try to clean and set an equal object inside the method, I lose the link with the model of view.

Heres is my code of view:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <input ng-model="car.name" type="text"/>
    <button ng-click="clearCar(car)">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Here is my code of .js:

```
var clearedCar = {
    name : ''    
}

$scope.clearCar = function(car){
    car = null;
    car = clearedCar;
}
```

So when I click the button, the input continues with the old value of the car.

> Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting car = clearedCar was just setting the temp variable used in the ng-repeat. What you want to do is update the value in the cars collection.

You can use $index to get the array index in the ng-click:

```
<button ng-click="clearCar($index)">Clear</button>
```

Then update the implementation of clearCar - note the angular.copy as well:

```
$scope.clearCar = function($index){
  $scope.cars[$index] = angular.copy(clearedCar);
};
```

Here's a Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/7xbshQYEcXEriYF0wGSd?p=preview